# UIButton Selected State Image Freezes on Autorotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, autorotate

I have a UIButton in the footer of UITableView. It has an empty checkbox as its unselected state, and a checked box as its selected state. It works perfectly in portrait, but if the view ever rotates to landscape, the button's image is frozen in whatever state it was when it rotated. The button still sends messages correctly after rotation, but the image does not change.

```
self.theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.theButton setImage:checkbox
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.theButton setImage:checkedBox
                forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

This code appears in the tableView:viewForFooterInSection: of my view controller. In the action linked to the button, I set `self.theButton.selected = !self.theButton.selected;`

What's going on?

Comment: This code is highly suspicious: `self.theButton.selected = !self.theButton.selected` You should not manipulate the selection state from inside a handler that gets called together with selection.

Comment: Without that code the button's selected state does not change at all, and the image shown is always the UIControlStateNormal state.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your button action

```
- (void)didTapCheckbox:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn =(UIButton *)sender;
    if (btn.selected == YES) {
        [btn setSelected:NO];
    }
    else{
        [btn setSelected:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't solve my problem... That result does remove the possibility of the selected property being incorrect. Thanks for the info!

Comment: you  write your button code in tableView:viewForFooterInSection: so when device go to landscape mode it is calling ones more so a new button is created. For that reason you face this problem

Answer (score 0):

instead of your code just do this

```
if(self.theButton == nil){
    self.theButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.theButton setImage:checkbox
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.theButton setImage:checkedBox
            forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```